# Arduino MIDI controller menuUsed was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, arduino

Trying to build a MIDI ribbon controller and found that someone had already written all the code necessary but when I try to upload it to the arduino I get the following error:

```
sketch_apr13a:122: error: 'menuUsed' was not declared in this scope
MenuBackend menu = MenuBackend(menuUsed,menuChanged);
                                ^
sketch_apr13a:122: error: 'menuChanged' was not declared in this scope
MenuBackend menu = MenuBackend(menuUsed,menuChanged);
                                  ^
exit status 1
'menuUsed' was not declared in this scope
```

Since I'm not really good at the whole coding thing I'm kinda stumped and simply grasping at straws by this point.

The entirety of the code can be found here: http://www.coagula.org/content/sites/default/files/source/MIDI_Ribbon_Controller_2.pde

The problem is at line 122 and probably 609 and 506 (since it's there the functions are)

Answer (score 1):

The function menuUsed is defined after you try to use it, so the compiler doesn't know the name yet.

What you can do is declare the name before you use it, with the static keyword.

```
static void menuUsed(MenuUseEvent used);
```

Of course same thing with menuChanged.

```
static void menuChanged(MenuChangeEvent changed);
```

You might run into compiler erros still with MenuUsedEvent and MenuChangedEvent though if they are not in a header somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that did it but now i just gotta figure out how to get it to work on a newer Arduino since things change over the period of 5 years(who would have thunk it).